# How do I disable Drag and Drop of highlighted Text globally?

Tags: mouse, input

How do I disable Drag and Drop of highlighted Text globally?

I know it's the OS doing it and not the Browsers or Editors, that's why I ask here for a Solution.

I'm using Kubuntu 18.04, but I didn't find a way to do it in Ubuntu either. I just want something that disables exactly that, no unrelated alternative or questions as to why I want it disabled.

There is tons of people annoyed at this feature, who never even got a reply at the other places they asked for, at least to my hour long search on google on this topic, so I hope my Question is gonna lead to a result for all of us, even if it is slightly hacky.

Best regards, Greg

Comment: What is the problem you face with drag-n-drop?

Comment: It is simple, whenever I highlight text in my browser, the editor or basically anywhere else, and I notice that I didn't highlight everything of it (what happens very very often to me) I try to re-select the line instantly, but instead of selecting the Line, it ends up Drag&Dropping instead of selecting the Line again. I fully understand why Drag&Drop is a thing, but I don't need it and I want to disable it entirely Systemwide, because it just slows me down massively.

Comment: Note: Dragging and Dropping Files from Dolphin to the Desktop and vice versa is something I do use, I just want Drag&Drop to not apply to highlighted Text

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, seems DropHelper doesn't provide any method to disable it. Set transparent color or default does not work, and the color must be non-null.
Therefore, trying to override DropHelper could work.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1231062)